# Tagged VLAN traffic goes only one way between mac and Linux

Tags: network

I used to have a Mac Mini 2018 with 10Gpbs ethernet connected to my 10Gbps switch. I had a tagged vlan to access my NAS. It worked very well last time I checked. I don't remember when I actually checked it last time, but at least everything - time machine, shared mounts, etc - seemed to be working fine) until I replaced it with a Mac Studio in april.

Then I realized something weird: traffic between Mac Studio and other macs on my network - 10Gbps or not - flows very well on tagged vlans. However, traffic between my Mac Studio and my NAS (and then between my Mac Studio and other Linux machines) goes only one way - Mac -> Linux, when using a tagged vlan. I get no traffic from the linux machines back to the mac. Linux <--> Linux works well, Mac <--> Mac works well.

I thought initially this was a Mac Studio issue. So I tested with a MacBook Pro M1. Same problem. I thought, oh well, this might be an M1 issue. I borrowed a MacBook Pro 2018, and again, same issue.

I used iperf3 for testing. I changed the switches - my network has mostly Ubiquiti switches, but I also have a small Mikrotik, and I tested with it. I even tested traffic between a mac and a Linux VM on ESXi running on a Mac Mini 2014. Still the same issue: traffic goes only one way between macOS and non-macOS. I also tried different Linux distros (Fedora, Ubuntu, TrueNAS Scale).

I am inclined to believe this is a Monterey issue, but my previous Mac Mini did have Monterey (although it was still one of the first versions).

The only thing I haven't tested is traffic to a linux machine that is not on a VM. All my tests were between a mac and a Linux hosted on a VM under ESXi. But still, traffic between Linux on different hosts/machines/esxi-nodes worked fine.

Traffic that goes on untagged vlan flows normally.

Any clue on how to debug this properly to get the culprit?

EDIT: just to clarify, I don't believe it is an MTU issue. I had jumbo frames enabled all the way (the Mac Studio had absolutely the same configuration as my previous Mac Mini, which had its MTU adjusted to 9000). And, as said, it does work between two macs and to Linux machines. I also tried with the standard MTU (1500), adjusting it all along the way, and same behavior.

EDIT #2: I manage to test traffic between the Mac and a Linux (Fedora) on bare metal, again, on tagged vlan. It worked. So maybe ESXi is the problem.

Comment: How did you determine that the traffic was one-way only? Have you tested with something similar to tcpdump/Wireshark? - If so, at which point did you inspect the traffic? (right before the Mac, right after the Linux box, inside the Linux box, inside the Mac, or?)

Comment: Hi! As said, I used iperf3 to test it when I realized I couldn't mount my shares. Using tcpdump, I see some traffic does flow - ie., it doesn't seem to be a physical problem. However, using iperf3, or trying to transfer files, it doesn't work from linux to mac.

Comment: Okay - that's a completely different problem than the one I imagined from reading your question. So your problem is not that traffic is one way - but that larger file transfers fail

Comment: No, my problem is that traffic on tagged vlans are reduced to almost nothing. It's not so much about large file transfers, but maybe to packet size. Anyway, iperf3 gets 0 bytes back from linux machines on a mac. Strangely, all flows fine between two macs.

Comment: Packet size is what I meant as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your own comments, the problem is really not that the traffic-flow is one-way only. Rather you problem is that large transfers fail.

Usually this is because you have the wrong MTU setting. For a 10 Gbps ethernet link, your NAS is probably setup for jumbo frames.

You'll want to disable that on the NAS, or enable jumbo frames on your Mac. You can do that from `System Preferences > Network`, click `Advanced` for your network interface and under the `Hardware` tab set MTU to for example `Jumbo (9000)`.

Comment: Not really. I mentioned that traffic without tagged-vlans work fine. I also had jumbo frames enabled on every component along the way. 
I also tested with MTU 1500 on 1Gbps macs. I didn't make any difference.

Comment: Okay - you need to answer to use tcpdump/Wireshark as I indicated. This is the correct way to diagnose your problem. Iperf3 on its own is not helpful here. You need to use those tools to tester whether the traffic is never sent from the NAS, never comes to the Mac or is never taken in by the Mac. I.e. measure just after the NAS, just before the Mac and internally in the Mac using software. That will help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: We do not have much information to work with here, but you might also be experienced traffic drops due to checksum errors or similar. It could be caused by driver issues - you can attempt disabling offloading. This can also cause a small amount of traffic to go through, but file transfers and iperf3 to fail.

Comment: Thanks @jksoegaard! I think you might be right. I tried running tcpdump, and I saw a lot of checksum error, though I am not sure if they are the culprit. How do I disable offloading?

Comment: I just tested with a Fedora box, without ESXi - things work. So a possible cause of the problem is ESXi - I just don't know where to look.